# Distinguishing tags that are film titles from normal tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

A few times I've been frustrated by the tags on this site.

The vast majority of tags are the names of films or programs, which makes finding suitable tags of the normal kind very difficult.

So, when someone asks a question, the tags can end up being sparse or inadequate.

It would be nice if title-tags and topic-tags could be easily distinguished.

Comment: Think it's bad? Wait 'til someone asks an `[analysis]` question about [*Analysis*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3728888/) :-)

Comment: So what tags are you having trouble with? Once you get used to the general ones in use it's not much of an issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D, the ones I'm having trouble with are the ones I'm not aware of.  There are 115 pages of tag names, and there's no way I or anyone else is going to look through them all to see what is appropriate when asking a question.  If there were a way to exclude the title-tags, we could see what the real tags are.

Comment: Related: [Custom tag styling (color) for a classification of tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278889/16201)

Comment: @Paulie_D says "*Once you get used to the general ones in use*".  I'd get used to them a lot faster if there were a list of them somewhere.  Or better yet, a list of all the tags that aren't names of specific films, people, TV shows, etc.

Comment: @Jenayah year padding will solve it

Comment: +1. Any kind of useful taxonomy has been absolutely drowned out by the noise created by making every piece of IP its own tag.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is an inherit limitation to the current tag system.  There have been numerous requests on meta.se over the years to make it more usable, such as [adding some level of organization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-stack-exchange-sites).  These generally get ignored or closed-declined.

So, until we can get some traction to overhaul this system (and it'd be a huge undertaking), we're stuck with the system as it is.

Comment: If it's ever going to happen, this is the obvious site for it to start with.  Not only are there a lot of tags, the categorization could be quite simple: title or not-title.  If it can't be made to work here, it can't be done anywhere.